# Java process as non-root consumes 100% CPU, but as root is fine

Tags: java, linux, docker, containers

I've been attempting to containerize a Java application with Docker. When I have the container run this process as a user other than root, CPU usage goes to 100% and stays there. However, with root, it is much more well behaved, sitting around 2%.

```
# docker run -d -p 8006:8006 -u root --name root app:latest
# docker run -d -p 8007:8006 -u nonroot --name nonroot app:latest                    
# ps aux | grep java
root     26537  9.2  4.1 174800 115636 ?       Sl   10:14   0:02 /opt/app/jvm16/bin/java -Xmx128M -Xms128M […]
nonroot  26808 94.8  6.2 202744 175368 ?       Sl   10:15   0:08 /opt/app/jvm16/bin/java -Xmx128M -Xms128M […]
```

The application functions identically with either root or a non-root user (it's not hung). But if I run this same application on a real (not inside a container) server, the CPU usage is fine for either root or non-root, hinting at a container-related cause.

Nothing (that I could find) on the Docker host lends insight, and java dumps inside the container don't point me to anything.

My question is: what could be an explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: what could be an explanation for this?

One possible explanation is that the application is repeatedly retrying something that works when the JVM is run as `root` and fails when tun as a normal user; i.e. it is a combination of a poorly designed application and a permission problem.

I would try the following to try to figure out what is happening:

- Use `jstack` to see what threads are active and what they are doing.  If the CPU is 100% and is is the JVM using the CPU, then there should be active threads.
- Use `strace` to see what syscalls the JVM is doing.
- Look at the applications log files and the docker and other system log files to see if there are any clues there.

Comment: Excellent work. You are correct, I ran an strace -F -p on the JVM's pid and indeed, it was repeatedly attempting to create a file in /tmp and getting permission denied. I adjusted permissions and it's working normally. Thanks!